# How to define same dependency for two different environments in gradle

Tags: java, gradle

On gradle file, I have two same dependencies from this first will work for actual code and the second for test, it is look redundant,

```
implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.12.7.1")
```

```
testImplementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.12.7.1")
```

So is it any other way to define these dependencies in a simple way may be in one line or something

Comment: it is redundant ; see java configurations hierarchy - see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_plugin_and_dependency_management

Comment: An implementation dependency should also show up in the testImplementation classpath, should it not? I would try simply removing the testImplementation version.